# Magento 2 theme fallback to blank regardless of parent

Tags: magento2, theme-fallback

I am attempting to create a custom theme utilizing the fallback mechanism. The issue I have encountered is that my theme is only falling back to blank.

This is occurring even though I have set the parent to be luma. I have confirmed in the 'core_config_data' table that my theme is applied. As well as the 'theme' table, my theme (vendor_theme) has the correct parent id that corresponds to luma.

theme.xml:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Vendor Theme</title>
<parent>Magento/luma</parent></theme>
```

registration.php:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/Vendor/vendor_theme',
__DIR__
);
```

Is there a step that I am missing here?

Also are there any comprehensive tutorials/guides related to custom theme development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets us create a child theme so our all custom themes in Magento 2 goes here:

> app/design/frontend/company_name/theme_name

Let us assume, our company name is mycompany and our theme name is basic. We need to create following directory structure for our theme:

```
<app>
     <design>
          <frontend>
              <mycompany>
                  <basic>
                      <etc>
                      <Magento_Theme>
                           <layout>
                                 default.xml
                      <media>
                           preview.png
                      <web>
                           <css>
                           <fonts>
                           <images>
                           <js>
                  theme.xml
                  registration.php
```

**mycompany :-**

The name of the theme package

**basic :-**
The name of the theme. We can have multiple named themes inside the mycompany folder.

**etc/view.xml :-**

This file is used to specify product image dimensions, thumbnails etc.

**Magento_Theme :-**
This directory is used to override existing Magento’s theme files.

**Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml :-**
By default Magento2 assumes that your theme’s logo file should be: `/web/media/logo.svg`
If you want some other file for logo, then you must declare it in `default.xml` file.

This file is also used to override default theme’s settings.

**media/preview.png :-**
The preview of current theme.

**web :-**
This directory contains all the theme’s static data like images, styles, javascript, fonts etc.

**registration.php :-**
This file is required to register our theme to Magento2 system.

**theme.xml :-**
This is a compulsory file that defines our theme name, its parent and optionally theme’s preview image.

**Creating theme files**

Let us now create our files one by one.

> theme.xml ( app/design/frontend/mycompany/basic/theme.xml )

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
   <title>Basic</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
   <parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!-- the parent theme -->
   <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image> <!-- theme's preview image -->
   </media>
</theme>
```

> registration.php ( app/design/frontend/mycompany/basic/registration.php )

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/mycompany/basic',
    __DIR__
);
```

> default.xml ( app/design/frontend/mycompany/basic/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml )

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
           <arguments>
              <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/my_logo.png</argument>
              <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
              <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
           </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

At this point, our theme is ready. Clear your cache and we will now select our new theme from admin.

Now, login to admin and move to following path:

```
Content -> Design -> Themes
```

You should see your theme listed.

Now go to:

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Design
```

Choose Main Website in front of Store View at top left. Now click

```
Desgin -> Design Theme
```

Uncheck Use Default checkbox and pick your theme. Click Save Config, clear your cache and your new theme is ready. Check your home page.

[For more detail see here.](http://ashutoshpandey.in/creating-a-theme-in-magento-2/)